# Arranging post in ascending order by date and not alphabetically

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I am having an issue the code below is giving me the post in an asc order alphabetically and I want it to be ascending order by DATE. I know that I have to use usort() or asort() but I have no clue where to insert it into this code.

```
<?php               
$query_date = custom_get_query_date_full(0);
global $more;
global $num_posts;
global $events_output;
$section_class = 'section';
$events_output = '';

if(!isset($num_posts)){
    $num_posts = -1;
}

// no section given
$args = array( 
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'post_type'=> 'event', 
    'posts_per_page' => $num_posts,     
    'meta_key' => 'date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'dateOrder' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array( 
            array('key' => 'date', 'value' => $query_date, 'compare' => '>' )
            //,array('key' => 'page', 'value' => $post->ID, 'compare' => 'LIKE')
    )
);  

$s = 0;
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if($the_query->post_count) {
    echo "<ul>\n";

    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

        $alt_class = '';
        if($s%2 != 0){
            $alt_class = ' alt';
        }

        $s++;
        if($s == $the_query->post_count){ $section_class = 'section-last';}

            $day_not_set = get_field('day_not_set');
            $date   = get_field('date');
            $day    = substr($date,6,2);
            $day_html = "<span class=\"time-day\">$day</span>";
            if(substr($day,0,1)==0){
                $day = substr($day,1,2);
            }
            $month  = substr($date,4,2);
            $year   = substr($date,2,2);            
            $month  = custom_get_month_string($month);
            if(!empty($day_not_set)){
                $day_html = "<span class=\"time-day\">20$year</span>";

            }
            $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'type' );
            $terms_class = '';
            foreach($terms as $term){
                $terms_class .= "$term->slug ";
            }


            $events_output .= "
            <li class=\"event-info $terms_class\">
                <time>$month $day_html</time>
                <h2><a href=\"" . get_permalink() . "\">" . get_the_title() . "</a></h2>" .
                str_replace('&nbsp;','',trim(get_field('teaser'))). "
                <div class=\"readmore\"><a href=\"" . get_permalink() . "\">View ></a></div>
            </li> \n";

    endwhile; 
    echo $events_output . "</ul>\n";
}
?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is:

```
'orderby' => 'post_date',
```